# What's better, C# or java?

Tags: c#, java

Due to my future course in Computer Science, I'm now going to start learning Java.

I've been teaching myself C# and some C++ up until now, so I'm gonna switch to Java.

Just trying to think about what that'll involve, and any suggestions for sites that talk about the various comparisons between C# and Java for someone moving to Java?

Much of the fundamental logical operations and the class/object system work in the same way, and without the need for pointers or the need for more memory management, like in C++, which is great. The comparisons between the framework are the most important I think.

Also reckoning on switching to a Mac and running Java that way.

This from Wikipedia:

---

"Both C# and Java are designed from the ground up as object oriented languages using dynamic dispatch, with syntax similar to C++ (C++ in turn derives from C). Neither language is a superset of C or C++, however. Both mainly use garbage collection as a means of reclaiming memory resources, rather than explicit deallocation of memory (though C# requires explicit deallocation for graphical, GDI+ objects, in which case it uses the IDisposable interface). Both include thread synchronization mechanisms as part of their language syntax."

Comment: can this question even be answered? you're unlikely to get a consensus here...

Comment: Learn as many languages as you can, rather than "switching", just write in all of them.

Comment: One the one hand, sharp == smart. On the other hand => coffee.

Comment: You can't just say one is better than the other. They both have there purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great article highlighting pros and cons of Java vs. C#:
http://www.veridicus.com/tummy/programming/java_vs_csharp.asp

And this one gives the syntactical differences for the same features:
http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html

However, as a beginner, I think you will find that the languages are quite similar.  C# may come in handy later, so rather than thinking of yourself as "moving" to Java, consider learning both.

Comment: That's really useful thanks. And if all that's true then I might be quite happy with Java to be honest. I still prefer the C# syntax style though, looks nicer to me some how y'know

Comment: @AlexW - you should not be basing your education / career decisions on trivial things like whether you like a specific language's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this can be answered. There are plenty of arguments back and forth over which is better around the place.

They both have their advantages and disadvantages, but it really comes down to your situation and personal preferences.